# If $ (1+3+5+\cdots +p)+ (1+3+5+\cdots +q)= (1+3+5+\cdots +r)$, Find the minimum value of $p+q+r$, $p>6$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> If $ (1+3+5+\cdots +p)+ (1+3+5+\cdots +q)= (1+3+5+\cdots +r)$,  Find the minimum value of $p+q+r$ if $p>6$

Let $p=2a-1$, $q=2b-1$, $r=2c-1$

$$(1+3+5+\cdots +p)+ (1+3+5+\cdots +q)= (1+3+5+\cdots +r)$$
$$\implies a^2+b^2=c^2$$
I have to minimize $f(a,b,c)=2a+2b+2c-3$ subject to $a^2+b^2=c^2$

On using Lagrange multipliers, 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=k\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
$$\implies 2=2ka$$
$$k=\frac{1}{a}$$
Similarly, $k=\frac{1}{b},k=\frac{1}{c}$.
So $a=b=c$. But $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Hence $a=b=c=0$. This is not possible.

Comment: What is the smallest and best-known Pythagorean triple?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee 3,4,5 ?

Comment: Your $f(a,b,c)$ is symmetrical function. And, obviously, $a=b=c$. But, where the restriction $a+b+c>0$?

Comment: $p>6$. So $2a-1>6$. This means, $a>3.5$

Comment: So $a=4, b=3,c=5$...  Or the next triple if you like, $5,12,13$...

Comment: @abiessu minima occurs when $a=b=c$

Comment: Okay... Are they restricted to integers?  If so, you won't get equality with the $a^2+b^2=c^2$ restriction.

Comment: yes. a,b,c are integers.

Comment: Then rest assured, you are looking for a "near-equilateral" right triangle that is as small as possible, with one leg greater than $3.5$, and there is really only one option.

Comment: @abiessu I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

p=7 -> S(p=7) = 16

q=5 -> S(q=5) = 9

r=9 -> S(r=9) = 25

*

p=23 -> S(p=23) = 144

q=17 -> S(q=17) = 81

r=29 -> S(r=29) = 225

*

p=29 -> S(p=29) = 225

q=15 -> S(q=15) = 64

r=33 -> S(r=33) = 289